# Fill inputs and click login button with webrequest in C#

Tags: c#, webrequest

How can I fill inputs and click LogIn button by their IDs?
The question could have been asked, but I couldn't find answer.

Comment: Take a look at Selenium framework

Comment: Sounds like jQuery. Seriously though, can you provide a *little* more information? Maybe some code? An example?

Comment: For example.
Webrequest request =Webrequest.Create("www.anysite.com/Login.aspx");

I want to fill username and password inputs and click login button on Login page with Webrequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really fill the inputs or click buttons with a web request.  What you can do is post data to the target of the form and the server side code should pick it up just like you filled in the inputs and  clicked the button.  If you're doing asp.net the target of the form will the the page itself so you could do something like this:

```
var request = new WebRequest(@"http:\\localhost\somePage.aspx");
request.Credentials= CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Method = "Post";
var postString = "SomeTextBox=Foo&SomeOtherTextBox=Bar";
var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

if you're using asp.net you should look into changing the ClientId mode of the controls to Predictable or you'll get SomeMasterPage_SomeContainer_SomeTextBox as your id (subject to change without notice as you add things into the control tree).  For the button click you'll want to add __EVENTTARGET=SomeButtonName to your post string.